# How to add multiple transport for parse-server logger?

Tags: node.js, logging, parse-platform, parse-server

I can access to the winston logger exposer by parse-server with `let logger = require('parse-server').logger;`

I would like to configure several transport file to have separate file with different logging levels like I can do with Winston:

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.File)({
      name: 'info-file',
      filename: 'filelog-info.log',
      level: 'info'
    }),
    new (winston.transports.File)({
      name: 'silly-file',
      filename: 'filelog-silly.log',
      level: 'silly'
    })
  ]
});
```

I've tried by usgin winston function like:
`logger.add(winston.transports.File, { ... });`

And with:

```
winston.configure({
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'somefile.log' })
    ]
  });
```

But it doesn't work.
I also saw this PR https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/pull/2363 but I coudn't understand how to add these transports from my index.js in `parse-server`.

Can someone give me some hints? Thanks!

Additional info:
parse-server version: 2.6.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to do similar as you. I wanted to add a transport to send logs to loggly.

I think the way to do it, is to use the `logger` object, that is exported together with the ParseServer object from the `parse-server` package.

The way how I added the loggly additional transport is the following:

```
const {ParseServer, logger} = require('parse-server');

const loggly = require('winston-loggly');

const parseApi = new ParseServer({
...
});

logger.adapter.addTransport(new loggly.Loggly({
  subdomain: 'my-subdomain',
  token: 'myToken',
  json: true
}));
```

I believe this is safe to do, as the logger is exported by the package in the same way as ParseServer.

Hope it helps. Lukas

Comment: Yes, I've figured out too. Forgot to update my question. Thank you to have posted it!

Answer (score 1):

for future reference (an example how I use winston-mongoDB), I'll just add my way as well:

1) create custom logger adapter

```
var _WinstonLoggerAdapter = require('parse-server/lib/Adapters/Logger/WinstonLoggerAdapter');

import * as WinstonMongoDb from 'winston-mongodb';

export function createCustomLoggerAdapter(options) {
    var winston = new _WinstonLoggerAdapter.WinstonLoggerAdapter(options);

    var WinstonMongoDbInstance: any = WinstonMongoDb.MongoDB;
    const transport = new WinstonMongoDbInstance({
        ...options,
        collection: 'ServerLog',
        level: 'error'
    });

    winston.addTransport(transport);
    return winston;
}
```

2) use it in parse config

```
var parseConfig = {
   ....,
   loggerAdapter: createCustomLoggerAdapter({db: databaseUri}),
}
```